# 1D Sturm-Liouville eigenfunctions for operator with discontinuous coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonality, sturm-liouville

I look for the eigenfunction-expansion coefficients corresponding to a given initial ($t=0$) profile. I am struggling with formulating the correct orthogonality relations for the eigenfunctions.

Imagine a particle diffusing on an interval $[0,L]$. 
For $x\in (0,w)$ a constant force $F(x)=-f \equiv -2g$ is acting towards origin.
The corresponding Smoluchowski equation for the probability is
$$
\partial_t p(x,t) = -\partial_{x} J, 
\qquad
-J = (\partial_x p(x,t) - F(x)p(x,t) )
$$
The eq. is separable as $p=X(x)T(t)$, where T'' = -c_n T, and
$$
X'' + 2g X + c_n X = 0, \qquad x\in[0,w) 
\\
X'' + c_n X = 0, \qquad x\in(w,L]
$$
If I impose boundary conditions $P(0)=0$ and $J(L)=0$ the possible solutions on each subinterval may be conveniently written as:
$$
X^1_n = B_n \exp(-gx) \sin(k_n x) , \qquad x\in[0,w) 
\\
X^2_n = Q_n\frac{  \cos(c_n(L-x)) }{ \cos(c_n(L-w)) }, \qquad x\in(w,L]
$$
where $c_n = g^2 + k_n^2$.
The matching condition for $x=w$ should be the continuity continuous $X$
and of the current, expressed as
$$
X^1_n(w) = X^2_n(w)
\\
X^1_n\,{'}(w) + 2g X^1_n(w) = X^2_n\,{'}(w)
$$
The second should be justified enough by integrating the ODE equation for $X$ over $\int_0^{w\pm\delta}$, and taking difference of the two terms (please correct me, were I wrong).
The two equations (requiring zero determinant of the matrix corresponding to the homogeneus system for $B_n, Q_n$) yield $Q_n=B_n \exp(-gw)\sin(k_n w)$ and condition for $c_n$:
$$
c_n \tan(c_n(L-w)) = +g + k_n \cot k_n w
$$

Numerically solving for $c_n$ i am able to specify $X^1_n, X^2_n$.

Now, I am looking for a way to find a orthogonality relations between the functions $X_n$ on whole interval $(0,L)$, assuming the correct weight function is $w(x)=\exp(2gx)$ on $(0,w)$  and unity on the rest I get
$$
const \times \delta_{nm} \stackrel{?}{=} 
\int_0^w \sin k_n x\sin k_m x
+ A_n A_m 
\int_w^L \frac{  \cos(c_n(L-x)) }{ \cos(c_n(L-w)) }
        \frac{  \cos(c_m(L-x)) }{ \cos(c_m(L-w)) }
\\
\text{where}
A_n = \exp(-gw)\sin(k_n w)
$$

But this seems not to work (almost sure I have the numerical quadrature ok).
I would appreciate all your insights :)